# What does the upper letter 'X' mean in jvm parameter?

Tags: java, jvm

JVM has many launch parameters, such as "-XX:SurvivorRatio", "-Xmn". So what does the upper letter 'X' mean in them?

### UPDATE

Sorry, but I know that:

> Options that begin with -X are non-standard (not guaranteed to be
>   supported on all VM implementations), and are subject to change
>   without notice in subsequent releases of the JDK. Options that are
>   specified with -XX are not stable and are subject to change without
>   notice.

#### I mean why choose 'X', rather than 'Y', 'Z', or 'x'?

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BGBCIEFC) says:

> Standard options are guaranteed to be supported by all implementations of the Java Virtual Machine (JVM). They are used for common actions, such as checking the version of the JRE, setting the class path, enabling verbose output, and so on.
>
> **Non-standard options** are general purpose options that are specific to the Java HotSpot Virtual Machine, so they are not guaranteed to be supported by all JVM implementations, and are subject to change. **These options start with `-X`.**
>
> **Advanced options** are not recommended for casual use. These are developer options used for tuning specific areas of the Java HotSpot Virtual Machine operation that often have specific system requirements and may require privileged access to system configuration parameters. They are also not guaranteed to be supported by all JVM implementations, and are subject to change. **Advanced options start with `-XX`.**

Answer (score 0):

> Non-standard, or -X, command line options are options that are
>   exclusive to Oracle **JRockit JVM** that change the behavior of **JRockit**
>   **JVM** to better suit the needs of different Java applications. These
>   options are all preceded by -X and will not work on other JVMs
>   (conversely, the non-standard options used by other JVMs won't work
>   with **JRockit JVM**).

Source: [Oracle website](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionX.html)

Answer (score 0):

> -XX Command-line Options
>
> This section describes Oracle JRockit JVM’s -XX command-line options;
>   these options are all prefaced by -XX. To implement some of the
>   options, specific system requirements must be met, otherwise, the
>   particular option will not work. We recommend that you use these
>   options only
>
> If you have a thorough understanding of your system. Are aware that,
>   if used improperly, these options can have negative effect on the
>   stability or performance of your system. These options are subject to
>   change without notice.

[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/jrdocs/refman/optionXX.html)